# Facebook Connect takes 30+ seconds to get an access_token

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, oauth, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to setup Facebook Connect authentication, but it takes upwards of 30 or more seconds to pull back an access token.  When I browse to the generated URL through my web browser, it comes back in less than 1 second.  The line of code that takes so long is `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))` I've tried replacing `WebRequest` with `WebClient` hoping that it would go faster, but no such luck.  Once I have the token, the next `WebRequest` that actually pulls the user data is quite fast.  I know this is not normal behavior, as I have seen plenty of websites do this authentication very quickly.  Any suggestions would be very appreciated.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
public ActionResult FBLogin()
{
    string uri = string.Format("http://{0}{1}/Shared/FBLogin", Request.Url.Host, Request.UrlIsDefaultPort ? string.Empty : string.Format(":{0}", Request.Url.Port));

    string code = Request["Code"];
    string state = Request["State"];

    if (Request["Code"].IsNullOrEmptyTrim())
    {
        state = MD5.GetMD5String(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        Session["State"] = state;

        string redirectUrl = string.Format("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope=email&state={2}", Settings.FacebookAppID, uri, state);

        return Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        if (state.Equals(Session["State"]))
        {
            Session["State"] = null;

            string tokenUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_secret={2}&code={3}", Settings.FacebookAppID, uri, CryptoProvider.DecryptString(Settings.FacebookSecretKey), code);
            string token = null;

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(tokenUrl);

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                token = ParseQueryString(sr.ReadToEnd())["access_token"];
            }

            if (token != null)
            {
                string userUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}", token);

                request = WebRequest.Create(userUrl);

                dynamic user;

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    user = serializer.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd());
                }

                if (user != null)
                {
                    // handle login
                }
            }
        }

        return Redirect(Request.Cookies["LastURL"].Value);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be noted that I'm running this in a debug environment.  Would it make a difference if it was on a production server with a real domain other than localhost:port?

Comment: The server location makes no difference.  I'm still stumped why this would take so long and a web browser is less than a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the code was correct.  It just suddenly sped up on it's own.  My best guess is that maybe it takes a few days for a newly created app on Facebook to fully propagate through it's servers causing it to take a while to locate.